# Custom validation for a Play 2.3.7 framework form not working

Tags: playframework-2.0, playframework-2.3

I have the following Address.java class in a Play 2.3.7 framework project but the custom validation function validate() to check the input of the country field is not working.

The field country should accept only: "AR", "BE", or "SL". But right now it is actually accepting any 2 characters string which means that validation is not working.

Can anyone please tell what is wrong here?

```
package models;

import play.data.*;
import play.data.validation.Constraints.*;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Address extends play.db.ebean.Model {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  public Long internalId;

  //CUSTOM :: Sample implementation of Hard Coded data
  public enum Country {
    ARDA("Arda", "AR"),
    BELGIUM("Belgium", "BE"),
    SMURFS_LAND("Smurfs Land", "SL");

    public String name;
    public String id;
    private Country(String name, String id) {
      this.name = name;
      this.id = id;
    }

    public static Country getById(String id) {
      for (Country c: values()) {
        if (c.id.equals(id)) {
          return c;
        }
      }
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Country not found => Bad id {"+id+"}");
    }
  }



  @Required
  @Pattern(
    value="[A-Z]{1}\\w*, [0-9]+",
    message="A street starts with an upper case, and ends with a number after a comma"
  )
  public String fullStreet;

  @Required
  public String county;

  @Required
  @MaxLength(2)
  public String country;

  //CUSTOM :: validation rules
  public String validate() {
    try {
      Country.getById(country);
      return null;
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
      return "Bad country : " +country;
    }
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this the top level object in the form, or a nested object?  `validate` is only executed on the top level object.

Comment: Thank you James. Yes, you are right, Address is a nested object of User (the top level object) and this is its class http://pastebin.com/Kv2aAC26 . I have tried to move validate to the User class with some modifications yet it didn't work.. I also tried to write a different validate() function for the name field inside the user class but still the form submits as if the validation is not there.

Comment: This is the validate() I was testing on the User class: public String validate() {
    if(name != "Tom"){
 return "invalid name";
    }
    else{
 return null;
    }
  }